# Data Stax Enterprise: how to export graph to GraphSON?

Tags: graph, datastax-enterprise

I have DSE server + DataStax Studio with connection (on my local Windows 10), inside DSE some graph, I need export this graph to GraphSON. File or string - whatever. There is no anything helpful in DSE documentation. I'm very confused, why this is so complex to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

```
stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
mapper = graph.io(graphson()).mapper().embedTypes(false).create().;
graph.io(graphson()).writer().mapper(mapper).create().writeVertex(stream, g.V().next(), BOTH);
stream.close();
stream.toString();
```

This works in DataStax Studio console.
Only one thing: result json has no indentation. I didn't find the way add it here.

Comment: from what I tried it only adds the last vertex or something like that?

Comment: this is probably what is the proper way now http://stackoverflow.com/q/43212765/986160 although it doesn't work with DSE that's why I asked a question. It works for in-memory Tinkergraph though

Comment: stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                mapper = graph.io(graphson()).mapper().embedTypes(false).create();
                graph.io(graphson()).writer().mapper(mapper).create().writeGraph(stream, graph);
stream.close();
stream.toString();

This is the final version what I have. As for TinkerPop in-memory - I would happy to use it, but there is no implementation in-memory graph for .Net.

Comment: so this works with DSE ? Tinkergraph is not avaiable for .NET?

Comment: I tried your version and I still get an empty string at the end..what version of DSE are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the graph.io method using one of the provided in/out formats.
It should be used this way :

`graph.io(graphson()).writeGraph("/tmp/mygraph.json")`

Documentation is available here : https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/graph/reference/refIo.html

You can reimport it the same way. If the graph is big you have to set transactional mode on.

```
schema.config().option("tx_autostart").set(true);
graph.io(graphson()).readGraph("/tmp/mygraph.json");
```